# Alterar link do botao de acordo com um radio

Tags: javascript, html, html5, link, radiobutton

Pessoal é uma coisa besta eu sei, mas estou quebrando a cabeça, preciso de ajuda quem puder agradeço.
.
estou fazendo um simples formulário, preciso que tenha uma pergunta de classificação, se a pessoa escolher a opção a o link muda exemplo pro google.com.br, se a pessoa escolher a opção b o link muda exemplo pro yahoo.com.br e se a pessoa escolher a opção c o link muda exemplo pro terra.com.br
.
cheguei a isso, mas não funciona:

```js
  jQuery(function($){
        $('#male, #female, #other').change(function(){
  var volume = $('#male').val();
    var volume = $('#female').val();
    var volume = $('#other').val();
             
  if (other == "other") {
             $('.LinkBotao').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com.br');
  }
  else if (male == "male") {
      $('.Linkbotao').attr('href', 'http://www.uol.com.br');
  }
  else if (female == "female") {
      $('.Linkbotao').attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com.br');
  }
 });
});
// JavaScript Document
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
     
     <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>  
     
     <br>
     <a href="#" class="LinkBotao" target="_blank">
       <input type="button" name="aderir" id="aderir" value="aderir"> 
     </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz algumas pequenas alterações mas tentei deixar o máximo possível parecido com o seu código.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="">

     <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="gender"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="gender"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" class="gender"> Other<br>  

     <br>
     <a href="#" class="LinkBotao" id="button">
       <input type="button" name="aderir" id="aderir" value="aderir"> 
     </a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($){
        $('.gender').click(function(){
        var volume = $(this).val();

        if (volume == "other") {
                $('#button').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com.br');
        }
        else if (volume == "male") {
            $('#button').attr('href', 'http://www.uol.com.br');
        }
        else if (volume == "female") {
            $('#button').attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com.br');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: puts mano não deu certo pro que eu preciso acrescentar

Comment: oque extamente você precisaria?

Comment: Eu fiz outra pergunta pra tentar explicar, eu preciso na verdade é de um form de nome, email e esses radio, que a cada radio ele mandasse pra uma programação em php, para disparar um email e voltar a outra pagina...achei que so com essa duvida conseguiria resolver, mas não consegui rsrsrsrs

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368192/alterar-o-link-de-um-bot%C3%A3o-radio-em-um-formulario

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa tratar o change pelo name

```
 $('input[type=radio][name=gender]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'male') {
            $('.LinkBotao').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com.br');
        }else if (this.value == 'female') {
            $('.LinkBotao').attr('href', 'http://www.uol.com.br');
        }else if (this.value == 'other') {
            $('.LinkBotao').attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com.br');
        }
 });
```