# {HELP} Alterarei o Link de um Botão Radio em Um Formulario, mas não chega no email

Tags: php, javascript, html5, email, radiobutton

Estou com um problema em um formulário, preciso que ao escolher um radio ele altere o link para onde as informações vão,isso eu consegui, porem no email não esta chegando as informações do form 
Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Arquivo `enviar.php`

```
<!-- language: php -->

    <?php

        <?php
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$nome  = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];
$month = $info['mon'];
$year = $info['year'];
$hour = $info['hours'];
$min = $info['minutes'];
$sec = $info['seconds'];
$current_date = "$date/$month/$year - $hour:$min:$sec";
$exibir_apos_enviar='mensagem-enviada.html';


mail("contato@eternus.com.br","Orçamento Alopecia","Nome: $nome \n\n Email: $email \n\n Telefone: $mobile \n\n IP: $ipaddress \n\n Contato em: $current_date");
echo "<script>window.location='$exibir_apos_enviar'</script>";
?>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($){
        $('.gender').click(function(){
        var volume = $(this).val();

        if (volume == "alopecia") {
                $('#form-action').attr('action', 'http://www.eternus.com.br/ebook-7-segredos-uso-protese-capilar/enviando-alopecia.php');
        }
        else if (volume == "calvice") {
            $('#form-action').attr('action', 'http://www.eternus.com.br/ebook-7-segredos-uso-protese-capilar/enviando-calvice.php');
        }
  else if (volume == "quimio") {
            $('#form-action').attr('action', 'http://www.eternus.com.br/ebook-7-segredos-uso-protese-capilar/enviando-quimio.php');
        }
        else if (volume == "outros") {
            $('#form-action').attr('action', 'http://www.eternus.com.br/ebook-7-segredos-uso-protese-capilar/enviando-outros.php');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form role="form" method="POST"  action="#" id="form-action">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Nome Completo</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="nome" id="nome" type="text" placeholder="Coloque Seu Nome Completo" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Email</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Coloque seu email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Celular/Whatsapp</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="mobile" id="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Coloque o Numero do Whatsapp">
</div>
<br>
<label>Para Qual Solução Será usado o eBook?</label>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="alopecia" class="gender">Alopecia<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="calvice" class="gender"> Calvice<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="quimio" class="gender"> Quimioterapia<br>  
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="outros" class="gender"> Outros<br>
     <br>



<div class="form-group last">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" name="aderir" id="aderir" value="Enviar" >
     
</div>
<p class="re-assure">Nós Não Compartilhamos seu Email. Sem spam. </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Cada radio vai enviar os dados do seu formulario por `$_POST` para um arquivo `.php` diferente, é isso?

Comment: isso exatamente isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, cada radio enviar os dados do seu formulario por $_POST para um arquivo .php diferente, ou seja, tudo que você precisa fazer é alterar o seu javascript/jquery da seguinte forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($){
        $('.gender').click(function(){
        var volume = $(this).val();

        if (volume == "other") {
                $('#phpcontactform').attr('action', 'http://www.site.com.br/enviando0.php');
        }
        else if (volume == "male") {
            $('#phpcontactform').attr('action', 'http://www.site.com.br/enviando1.php');
        }
        else if (volume == "female") {
            $('#phpcontactform').attr('action', 'http://www.site.com.br/enviando2.php');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Com isso ele irá trocar o `action` do formulario sempre que você alterar o radio e com isso mandar os dados do seu formulario para outro arquivo de acordo com o radio selecionado.

Comment: Obrigado man, esta indo pro php de destino porem não está chegando no email os dados de nome, email e telefone, esta chegando email sem os dados

Comment: editei a pergunta pra vc ver como eu fiz, sera que consegue me ajudar man?

Comment: dá um `var_dump($_POST)` no seu arquivo `enviar.php`

Comment: o que seria isso?

Comment: para verificar se os dados do formulario estão chegando no seu arquivo `enviar.php` através do `post`

Comment: não sei como fazer isso rsrsrs

Comment: $nome=$_POST['nome'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
$mensagem=$_POST['mensagem'];
$exibir_apos_enviar='enviado-com-sucesso.html';

Comment: vou editar a pergunta com o codigo que tenho ate o momento

Comment: antes do `$nome=$_POST['nome'];` você coloca `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: coloquei mas não chegou no email da mesma forma

Comment: esqueci de mais uma parte `var_dump($_POST);exit();` , dessa forma vai fazer com que o código pare e apareça se os dados estão chegando

Comment: entendi....obrigado man